# Asynchronous HTTPrequest from PHP

Tags: php, httprequest, http-post

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Asynchronous HTTP requests in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240267/asynchronous-http-requests-in-php)

I want to be able to do a POST or GET request from scriptA.php to scriptB.php.
But I don't want scriptA.php to have to wait until scriptB.php is done doing its job. I want to be able to send the request, and don't expect for the result.

Comment: Are you saying that the original request is being sent to scriptA.php, but you want to do something with that data concurrently using scriptB.php before scriptA.php is done executing? If so, just use cURL  (if available) to send a request to scriptB.php, passing along $_GET and/or $_POST so that you can access them in scriptB. If CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER is not set, then PHP won't wait for a response from the second page, so scriptA will continue processing. If you don't have cURL installed, you'll have to do this through fsocket.

Comment: On which operating system is your script running?